# Stock trading for Non resident f1-OPT TAX

Tags: united-states, stocks, income-tax, non-resident, capital-gains-tax

I am a non resident alien in F1- Opt status. I purchased some stock and sold them in loss.How would I claim loss in 1040 NR form ? I read the IRS website and found it-

"Nonresident alien students and scholars and alien employees of foreign governments and international organizations who, at the time of their arrival in the United States, intend to reside in the United States for longer than 1 year are subject to the 30 percent taxation on their capital gains during any tax year (usually calendar year) in which they are present in the United States for 183 days or more, unless a tax treaty provides for a lesser rate of taxation.

This assumes that such capital gains are not effectively connected with the conduct of a United States trade or business"

Does stock investment related to United States trade or business?
or should I fill up Schedule D and 1099 - B form for stock ?

Is the rule different for mutual fund and crypto?

Would be really glad if someone can help me ?